# How to create Observable from Array?

Tags: java, rx-java

When I use `Observable.fromArray` (which should work based on this [picture](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html))

```
double[] arr = new double[4];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
// The type of element is double[] here for some reason
return Observable.fromArray(arr).map(element -> ...);
```

Essentially `Observable.fromArray(arr)` works the same as `Observable.just(arr)`, why is that (I wanna get 1, 2, 3, 4 as my elements)?

Comment: Primitive arrays are not supported with `fromArray`.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3518

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3518:

```
char[] chars = "string".toCharArray();

Observable.range(0, chars.length).map(i -> chars[i]).subscribe(...)
```